# Oracle Number (10, 0) decimal in (C#) code

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, c#

The following query is executed to add a new column to an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD COLUMN1 NUMBER(10, 0) DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL.
```

Using DBForge to check the database, result in NUMBER (10, 0) column

An OracleConnection (of Devart dotConnect) is used and the NumberMapping property is set:

```
connection.NumberMappings.Add(OracleNumberType.Integer, 6, 10, typeof(int));
connection.NumberMappings.Add(OracleNumberType.Integer, 11, 19, typeof(long));
```

As soon as the next query "SELECT * FROM TABLE1" is executed, the DataTable contains 'COLUMN1' column with DataType decimal! It should be an integer according to the NumberMappings.

If the 'DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL' part is removed in the query, the 'COLUMN1' DataType is Int32.

I have checked the schema of the (Data)Table as well and noticed the NumericPrecision is set to 0 (zero). It should be 10.

```
DataTable schema ;
using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
{
    schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
}
```

The issue only occurs in certain tables (not all). Does Oracle provide a way to modify or fix the NumericPrecision?

Comment: I know nothing about Devart dotConnect, but number(10) is too big for int32 (max value ~2e9)

Comment: `NUMBER(10)` will show `DATA_PRECISION` as `10` when you check the dictionary files (eg `USER_TAB_COLS`).  I don't see anything that needs to be fixed within Oracle.